# Java Scanner ignores answer

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hi it's my first post here and I have a problem:

I have a program in which, at some point, asks the user if he wants to share the stars, and if he supposedly does, the program goes back to collecting them and after some time comes back to the question if he wants to share them again.

The problem is that, when the user comes back to that point, the program ignores whatever answer u give to it and goes to the "else answer block".

It looks like this:

```
"Do you want to share your stars?

yes

Please answer with yes or no"
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
static Scanner skan = new Scanner(System.in);
static int starCount = 0;
static Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    starReaching();

}

static void starReaching() {
    boolean starCollected = false;
    int i = 0;
    int j = random.nextInt(101);

    while (i < j) {
        i++;
        System.out.println("Stars are out of reach");
    }
    if (i > j || i == j) {
        starCollected = true;
    }
    if (starCollected == true) {
        starCollector();
    }
}

static void starCollector() {
    System.out.println("You caught a star !");
    starCount++;
    if (starCount == 10) {
        System.out.println("You have 10 stars ! :)");
        System.out.println("Do you want to share your stars?");
        String line = skan.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("yes")) {
            skan.reset();
            starGiver();
        } else if (line.equals("no")) {
            wishMaker();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please answer with yes or no");
            System.exit(0); 
        }
    } else {
        starReaching();
    }
}

static void starGiver() {
    System.out.println("How many do you want to share?");
    int starsToShare = skan.nextInt();
    if (starsToShare < 10 || starsToShare == 10 && starsToShare > 0) {
        starCount = starCount - starsToShare;
        System.out.println("Stars shared !");
        System.out.println("You now have " + starCount + " stars");
        System.out.println("Go collect them again!");
        starReaching();
    } else if (starsToShare > 10) {
        System.out.println("You don't have enough stars to share that much!");
        starGiver();
    } else {
        System.out.println("That's not a valid option");
        starGiver();
    }
}

static void wishMaker() {

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `skan.nextLine()` you read a new line and advance the scanner's pointer, and this is the reason your code is failing: you're calling this too often.

Instead of

```
if (skan.nextLine().equals("yes")) {
    skan.reset();
    starGiver();
} else if (skan.nextLine().equals("no")) {
    wishMaker();
} else {
```

do:

```
String line = scan.nextLine(); // read from Scanner **once** only
if (line.equals("yes")) {
    skan.reset();
    starGiver();
} else if (line.equals("no")) {
    wishMaker();
} else {
```

Comment: after changing to 
`String line = skan.nextLine();
   if (line.equals("yes")) {
    skan.reset();
    starGiver();
   } else if (line.equals("no")) {
    wishMaker();`

the message now is
"Do you want to share your stars?
Please answer with yes or no"

so now it dosent even wait for input

Comment: @Selvidian: You are having other problems with your code, likely in code not shown. Are you calling any other Scanner methods other than `nextLine()`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i've found the little bugger, i was using skan.nextInt without using skan.nextLine after that, thank you for the quick help, much love